# Safari Websocket Handshake Error

Tags: websocket, safari, handshake

I am building my own Http Server with built in Support for Websockets for a school project.

I mainly tested everything on Chrome and everything looks good, but I am having problems with Safari (10.0.2).

When establishing the Handshake `WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.213' failed: Status line contains non-ASCII character` appears as an Error in the development console, keep in mind, Chrome works as expected.

Here are the Exchanged Headers

## Request Header (Safari => Server)

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 192.168.0.213
Origin: http://192.168.0.213
Cookie: session=MDQ5M2UzYTctODg5NC00ZTEwLWJlOWEtYjBiZTRkNzdiYTRj
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 9/Mj26XS0JxG+Y+lDTvMcQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.2 Safari/602.3.12
```

## Response Header (Server => Safari)

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection:Upgrade
Upgrade:websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:rpx9CefKAgOdM7RzjhLuWEcCIso=
```

*Raw Response Header*

```
[72][84][84][80][47][49][46][49][32][49]
[48][49][32][83][119][105][116][99][104][105]
[110][103][32][80][114][111][116][111][99][111]
[108][115][13][10][67][111][110][110][101][99]
[116][105][111][110][58][85][112][103][114][97]
[100][101][13][10][85][112][103][114][97][100]
[101][58][87][101][98][115][111][99][107][101]
[116][13][10][83][101][99][45][87][101][98]
[83][111][99][107][101][116][45][65][99][99]
[101][112][116][58][53][120][86][118][113][57]
[52][121][97][53][84][56][51][88][65][82]
[115][78][119][74][69][88][97][78][97][108]
[99][61][13][10][13][10]
```

*How it is beeng generated (C#)*

```
string handshakeString = $"HTTP/1.1 {(int)StatusCode.SwitchingProtocols} {StatusCode.SwitchingProtocols.GetStatusMessage()}" + Environment.NewLine
                                                 + "Connection:Upgrade" + Environment.NewLine
                                                 + "Upgrade:Websocket" + Environment.NewLine
                                                 + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:" + Convert.ToBase64String($"{_initHeader["Sec-WebSocket-Key"]}258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11".Sha1()) + Environment.NewLine
                                                 + Environment.NewLine;
byte[] handshake = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(handshakeString); // <- There is the ASCII part
await SendFrameData(OpCode.Text, handshake); // This frame neither gets fragmented or masked
```

I understand, that there must be an issue with the encoding of the header, but this header gets encoded as ASCII and send with an OpCode 0x1 (Text) to the Client and it is working in Chrome. Am I missing some header keys/values?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Clearly it is not all ASCII or else Safari would not be complaining about it.  What does your server code look like?  What do the actual raw bytes being transmitted look like?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i just added some of the server code and the raw bytes.

Comment: What does `SendFrameData()` actually do? At this stage of communications, the protocol is still HTTP, not WebSocket, so if `SendFrameData(OpCode.Text, handshake)` is not sending `handshake` *as-is*, but is wrapping it within a WebSocket frame, then you are corrupting the communications. You can't send WebSocket frames until *after* the HTTP `101` response has been sent.

Comment: Well, thats exactly what is done. This function creates Websocket frames whos payload is the handshake, somehow Chrome can deal with it and accept the Websocket, however Safari is not able to deal with it. Now I am sending the Header directly on to the socket and it works flawlessly!, Thanks!

Comment: Wrapping the handshake response in a WebSocket frame violates the WebSocket protocol spec, [RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455). I don't know why Chrome accepts it, but Safari is doing the right thing by rejecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own Question. Thanks Remy Lebeau!

The Handshake was wrapped in a Websocket frame. This violates [RFC 5455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). So the handshake directly needs to be send over the socket.